# What is the equivalent for fs.readFileSync regard s3.getObject

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using `fs.readFileSync` on my local machine like this:

`const content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'latin1')`

Now I'm trying to replace it with `s3.getObject` and I can't figure out how.

This is how I use it but the `content` return empty

```
s3.getObject(getParams, function(err, data) {
    // Handle any error and exit
    if (err)
        return err

  // No error happened
  // Convert Body from a Buffer to a String

  const content = data.Body.toString('latin1')
})
```

Comment: Promisify it if there isn't a built-in promisified version?

Comment: You can't read it synchronously. Only using async/await and Promise/priomisify lib to wrap a callback